Convert word to pdf using python in Linux
I have written a python script that has a function which converts word to pdf. I was using comtypes.client library and it worked expectedly. Now I deployed that script on linux azure function app and got to know that comtypes doesn't work on Linux. I have tried multiple solutions but none of them work as expected. Let me know if there is a solution that uses python library which works on linux azure function app.

see also: How to convert an office document to PDF using Azure Functions v2 and Docker
